# Altering forms from Silverstripe CMS

Tags: silverstripe

I'm a beginner to silverstripe and am happy for someone to just point to a relevant section of the docs if they know where I should read. I just haven't been able to find very good instruction on this.

So I have created an Enquiry form for a site I'm building, and have:

```
/template/Layout/EnquiryPage.ss
/mysite/code/EnquiryPage.php
/mysite/code/EnquirySubmission.php
```

All are working well, users can upload enquirers and they are stored in the database.

What I want however is, as an admin, to be able to see/edit/delete these forms from within a tab in the CMS. What do I need to know about to be able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I found: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/modeladmin/ 
which I think is what I want. If anyone has any other links that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [ModelAdmin](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/modeladmin/).

Pro tip: Don't forget to set your `canEdit()`, `canDelete()`, etc. permission methods on your DataObject.

Comment: UncleCheese again! Been watching your vids! Thanks heaps for those by the way. I found this page just before and it does seem like the area I want. Thanks again!

Comment: @StefanOrr you could also https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms to create forms in the admin